# Incorrect syntax near the keyword UNION

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone tell me what wrong I have written in the following query so that this error message is being shown.

```
strSelectQuery = "SELECT LED_ID AS PK_ID, FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME AS NAME"
                        + " FROM M_LEADERLED INNER JOIN M_USER_DETAILS"
                        + " ON M_LEADERLED.LED_ID = M_USER_DETAILS.PK_ID"
                        + " WHERE (M_LEADERLED.LEADER_ID = " + Session["UserID"].ToString() + ""
                        + " AND M_USER_DETAILS.ACTIVE = 1 AND M_LEADERLED.START_DATE <= Getdate()"
                        + " AND M_LEADERLED.END_DATE > Getdate())"
                        + " UNION SELECT PK_ID, FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME AS NAME"
                        + " FROM M_USER_DETAILS WHERE PK_ID = " + Session["UserID"].ToString() + ";";
```

Comment: which error message might that be?

Comment: If you are getting this while executing this query, then I suggest you to print the query string and run it manually once

Comment: Are the PK_ID and LED_ID fields numbers or strings?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show the full value of strSelectQuery?

Answer (score 3):

You need single quotes around the output of the `Session["UserID"].ToString()`, like this:

```
+ " WHERE (M_LEADERLED.LEADER_ID = '" + Session["UserID"].ToString() + "'"
```

Should i also mention that you should be:

- doing a null check on `Session["UserID"]` before you try to `ToString()` it?
- don't ever ever ever do your SQL this way if you can avoid it - it is a massive security hole (check out [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

---

**EDIT:** based on updated information supplied by the OP, because the keys are numeric you don't have to single quote them. You really do need to check the output of `Session["UserID"]` (because it could be garbage or null), and you need to show us the fully constructed SQL string.